# how to make data nested row to be a separated column without null value in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

when executing this query

```
SELECT
  event_name,
  user_pseudo_id,
  event_timestamp,
  user_properties
FROM
  `project.analytics_000.events_*`
```

I have repeated record like this on my BigQuery

[image]

as you can see, the user properties is a record. I want to flatten the table to be like this

[image]

I have tried to unnest the data using this query

```
SELECT
  event_name,
  event_timestamp,
  user_pseudo_id,
  CASE WHEN user_data.key = 'customer_type' THEN user_data.value.string_value ELSE NULL END AS customer_type,
  CASE WHEN user_data.key = 'has_sales_tag' THEN user_data.value.string_value ELSE NULL END AS has_sales_tag,
FROM
  `blueray-cargo.analytics_296834888.events_*`,
UNNEST(user_properties) AS user_data
```

but it will have separated row with a lot of null value like this

[image]

I try to `GROUP BY` the data but it will throw error

[image]

so how to make nested row to be a separated unnested column without null value in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider below using scalar subquery.

```sql
SELECT event_name, user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp,
       (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) WHERE key = 'customer_type') AS customer_type,
       (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) WHERE key = 'has_sales_tag') AS has_sales_tag,
  FROM `events`;
```

**Query results**

[image]